# Ajax / php folder listing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a strange problem with the listing of a intranet directory, i searched on google and stackoverflow some notice but without luck.

This is the very simple ajax call:

```
function mostra_cartella() {
$.ajax({
    url:'risorse/leggi_directory.php',
    data: { cliente: document.getElementById("cliente").value,
            codice : document.getElementById("codice").value,
            root   : "/Archivio CAD-CAM/"
          },
    dataType:"html",
    cache:false,
    }).done(function(html) {
        $("#cartella_file").html(html);
    });

}
```

and this is the php file return me the folders list:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');

$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$codice = $_GET['codice'];
$cliente = $_GET['cliente'];
$root = $_GET['root'];

$path = "//".$host.$root.$cliente."/".$codice."</br>";
echo $path;

$path2 = "//192.168.0.10/Archivio CAD-CAM/GD/";
echo $path2;



    echo "<div id='listato'>";
    echo "<ul id='multi'>";
    if($handler = opendir($path)){
     while(($file = readdir($handler)) !== false) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo "<li>".$file."</li>";
      }
        }
    }
        else {
         echo "La directory non è stata trovata o risulta vuota";
        }

    closedir($handler);
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</ul>";

?>
</html>
```

The problem is that:the result of variable $path and $path2 is the same EVER (it's for my test) and the php page is called EVER from the ajax call.

First attempt:

if use the $path2 variable to create the handler,and not with the data pass with ajax,everything works fine,because the path is already in php file? (do not know)

second attempt:

if i use variable $path (same url of $path2),composed by data fropm ajax call,don't return me anything,and opendir() fail to create handler and give me the error:

**Warning: opendir(//192.168.0.10/Archivio CAD-CAM/GD/</br>,//192.168.0.10/Archivio CAD-CAM/GD/</br>): in C:\wamp\www\Gestionale Programmi\risorse\leggi_directory.php on line 46**

What is the difference between the two methods?

Why one work and the other not even though the variables $path and $path2 have the same result?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `.$codice."</br>"` How about `</br>` in path? you tried to remove it and put there `/` instead?

Comment: as everyone says -- (//192.168.0.10/Archivio CAD-CAM/GD/</br>) should be, (//192.168.0.10/Archivio CAD-CAM/GD/) -- why did you put ("</br>") in the first place if you are defining a file path?? also check ( $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT']) or ('PATH_TRANSLATED') for paths instead of directly putting in a file path. --- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be because you appending `<br/>` inside `$path`

Comment: I have added </br> to see better the two echo of the variable,there's a inattention error. Thanks for help